# How do I manage jre/lib/ext jars in a Jenkins/Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependency-management

I'm trying to set up a build for my team on a Jenkins box.  They are using a product whose documentation says to drop 2 jar files and a .properties file in the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext directory.

Since this Jenkins build box is managed by another team and houses many builds, I feel that it is a bad idea to tell them to install these files on all the slaves that may build this project. (especially if we were to need to upgrade/change settings/etc.)

Is there a best-practice for managing this sort of thing?

Things I've tried so far:

- Installing it in the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext == works.
- Installing the jar files in the maven repo and dropping the properties file in src/main/resources == doesn't work (it looks in $M2_REPO/PATH/TO/JAR/jarname.properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is really necessary to deploy than into lib/ext, the easiest way would be to provide a custom jdk for your build (call it Java6_With_MyProduct), in which you provide the zipped/tar'gz'ed) jdk.

Ask your administrators to include it into the Jenkins configuration.

That way, YOUR (and only your builds) would get your extended jdk.

Alternatively, you could use the -Djava.ext.dirs system property to override the extension directory. That way, your would

- copy your extension into your workspace as a prebuild step
- copy the original extensions from $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext into the same directory
- set -Djava.ext.dirs=$WORKSPACE/myextensions as MAVEN_OPTS (only if the extension is required to actually BUILD the project)
- add -Djava.ext.dirs=$WORKSPACE/myextensions to the argLine for surefire and failfast plugins

The open question is: do your really need those extensions to BUILD your project?

Comment: No, but once it's built, how do I get pretty graphs about my integration tests unless I run the build via Jenkins?

Comment: @JBristow In that case, for solution 2) you have to include the system property in your Surefire/Failfast plugin's argsLine as well. I will update answer.